# How to paste multiple commands with -y

Tags: linux, debian, bash, google-cloud-platform

I can paste multiple commands like these:

```
python3 -m pip install sklearn
python3 -m pip install psutil
```

but if I paste multiple commands with -y only first command processed and everything else is swallowed

```
sudo apt-get -y install htop
sudo apt-get -y install p7zip-full
```

This happens in Google Cloud web-console (its like SSH client in a web browser)
OS Debian 9

How can I make it work?

Comment: are you sure of that ? as -y will automatic install any package you put. but to be sure please put the full output.

Comment: to clarify - it installs htop and that's it.. there is nothing else after htop is installed. Just empty bash prompt waiting for a command. p7zip is not installed

Comment: Why didn't you `sudo apt-get -y install htop p7zip-full`?

Comment: Because I didn't know its possible. This is why I asked. Put it as an answer for dummies like me

Answer (score 1):

maybe with :

```
sudo apt-get -y install htop && sudo apt-get -y install p7zip-full
```